# Haskell: call function from input?

Tags: haskell

I'm using [this](http://rextester.com/l/haskell_online_compiler) online compiler.

I have this code:

```
main = do
    aa    
aa list lib = print (translate list lib)    
translate ls dict = [ b | (a,b) <- dict, a `elem` ls ]
```

And this user input:

```
aa [1,2,3] [(1,2), (1,4), (2,4), (2,5)]
```

And now I get error, because `main` calls `aa` without arguments

How do I call this `aa` function with these arguments from input? What should I put in `main`?

Comment: Try providing a list of values (`list`) and a list of tuples (`dict`) such as `main = aa [1::Int,2,3] [(2,3),(4,9),(5,1)]`.  If that doesn't answer your question then perhaps you can say more about what you are doing and what you want.

Comment: You mean from _user_ input? You are maybe looking for `readLn`

Comment: To answer this question, you first need to decide what the format of the user input is.

Answer (score 1):

You may actually read and auto-parse things in Haskell using readLn IO.

```
main = do
    (l1 :: [Int]) <- readLn
    (l2 :: [(Int, Int)]) <- readLn
    aa l1 l2
```

Or even with one-liner

```
main = join $ aa <$> readLn <*> readLn
```